# Return Values of Entire Table Using PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to run what I thought was going to be a simple query. 
I want to return a database table just the values) in the same 2D style it is written in into $data[i][k]

I am using PHP's PDO, and the closest I have been able to get is:

```
$result=$database->query("SELECT * FROM `garage_statistics`",$bind = null,$fetch = 'FETCH_COLUMN');
$this->statement = $this->pdo->prepare($query);
$result = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN,1);
```

Which returns

```
0 => string 'Garage2' (length=1)
1 => string 'Garage3' (length=7)
2 => string 'Garage4' (length=7)
3 => string 'Garage6' (length=7)
4 => string 'Garage7' (length=7)
```

However I can't get it to loop for all the columns. I tried fetchall and got back:

```
array (size=10)
0 => 
array (size=14)
  'name' => string 't' (length=1)
  0 => string 't' (length=1)
  'tablename' => string 't' (length=1)
  1 => string 't' (length=1)
  'numfloors' => string '3' (length=1)
  2 => string '3' (length=1)
  'status' => string '4' (length=1)
  3 => string '4' (length=1)
  'numspots' => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
  'spotsinuse' => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  'time' => string '2012-12-07 13:47:13' (length=19)
  6 => string '2012-12-07 13:47:13' (length=19)
1 => 
array (size=14)
  'name' => string 'Garage 3' (length=8)
  0 => string 'Garage 3' (length=8)
  'tablename' => string 'Garage3' (length=7)
  1 => string 'Garage3' (length=7)
  'numfloors' => string '2' (length=1)
  2 => string '2' (length=1)
  'status' => string '3' (length=1)
  3 => string '3' (length=1)
  'numspots' => string '0' (length=1)
  4 => string '0' (length=1)
  'spotsinuse' => string '0' (length=1)
  5 => string '0' (length=1)
  'time' => string '2012-12-07 13:49:46' (length=19)
   6 => string '2012-12-07 13:49:46' (length=19)
```

While this does contain all the data, it has so much stuff that I don't want.

Is there a simple way to get a basic 2D array of a table using PDO?

Comment: Solved it. Use FETCH_NUM

Answer (score 0):

$result = $this->statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

Returns correct type

Comment: PDO::FETCH_ASSOC is more user friendly imo.